# EF Using FK's for 1:1 Relationships

Tags: entity-framework

when working with my POCO objects, I prefer to delay instantiation of navigation properties as much as possible (performance reasons).  Instead I'd like to use the FK Value on my entities.

For Example:

```
class Car
{ 
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public int RegistrationId {get;set;}
   public virtual Registration Registrations {get;set;} // Nav Property
}

class Registration
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public int CarId {get;set;}
   public virtual Car Car {get;set;} // Nav Property
}
```

Given this is a 1:1 Relationship, how can I get EF to populate my FK Values for me? (using EF 6.0.1)

Comment: Are Car.RegistrationId and Registration.CarId configured/mapped?

Comment: Registration Mapping -> this.HasRequired(t => t.Car)
                .WithRequiredDependent(t => t.Registration)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

Comment: I suppose at this point I'm just confused as to what specifically you want to happen. Based on the code you have currently a Car's RegistrationId property should populate when an instance of Car is loaded, and vice-versa for Registration.

Comment: I would have thought so too, but the FK's values are 0 in the database and they are not getting persisted or loaded with the navigation properties PK